# Display Issue with resized PNG images in MFC application

Tags: mfc, png

in our MFC application, we are using lots of images(jpg and png). when we launch the application we are loading all the images into a map.
whenever we resize the application we are resizing all the images in the map.
we are using nearly 300 images so it is taking 3secs to resize the application.
we tried to split the images into different maps based on requirement but that also has an impact on performance. managing is also becoming tuff.

Along with this, there is one more issue on quality when we resize .png images. After resizing all the transparent area is becoming a blur.

In our code we are using CxImage class for loading, rendering and resizing the image.

Below is the code sample. Please suggest how to handle these kind of issues.
can we use SVG files in MFC application?

Loading the image

```cpp
    int CPicture::Load(CString sFileName)
    {
        CString strFullFileName = sFileName;
        CString strOrigFileName = strFullFileName;
        int nRet = strFullFileName.ReverseFind('.');
        if(nRet != -1)
        {
            strFullFileName.Insert(nRet, _T("_bl"));
        }

        if( FALSE == CheckIfFileExists(strFullFileName) )
        {
            strFullFileName = strOrigFileName;
        }
    }

    CString ss = sFileName;
    ss.MakeLower();

    if(ss.Find(_T(".png")) > 0)
    {
        // forcefully loading new images 
        if(m_pXImage)
        {
            SAFE_DELETE(m_pXImage);
        }
        if(NULL == m_pXImage)
        {
            m_pXImage = new CxImage(strFullFileName, CXIMAGE_FORMAT_PNG);
        }
        if (!m_pXImage->IsValid()){
            SAFE_DELETE(m_pXImage);
            //AfxMessageBox(m_pXImage->GetLastError());
            return E_IMAGEFILE_NOTLOADED;
        }
        msName = strFullFileName;
        return E_IMAGEFILE_LOADED;
    }

    if(ss.Find(_T(".gif")) > 0)
    {
        // forcefully loading new images 
        if(m_pXImage)
        {
            SAFE_DELETE(m_pXImage);
        }
        if(NULL == m_pXImage)
        {
            m_pXImage = new CxImage(strFullFileName, CXIMAGE_FORMAT_GIF);
        }
        if (!m_pXImage->IsValid()){
            SAFE_DELETE(m_pXImage);
            //AfxMessageBox(m_pXImage->GetLastError());
            return E_IMAGEFILE_NOTLOADED;
        }
        msName = strFullFileName;
        return E_IMAGEFILE_LOADED;
    }
    int bResult = E_IMAGEFILE_NOTLOADED;
    if (m_pPicture != NULL)
        UnLoad();

    if (m_pPicture == NULL)
    {
        CFile           cFile;
        CFileException  fileException;

        if(!cFile.Open(strFullFileName, CFile::modeRead | CFile::typeBinary, &fileException))
        {
            if(!cFile.Open(strFullFileName, CFile::modeRead | CFile::typeBinary, &fileException))
            {
                return E_IMAGEFILE_MISSING;
            }
        }

        msName = strFullFileName;

        if(cFile.GetLength() <= 0)
        {
            cFile.Close(); 

            return E_IMAGEFILE_MISSING;
        }

        int nSize = static_cast<int> (cFile.GetLength());
        BYTE* pBuff = new BYTE[nSize];

        if (cFile.Read(pBuff, nSize) > 0)
        {
            if(LoadFromBuffer(pBuff, nSize))
            {
                bResult = E_IMAGEFILE_LOADED;
            }
            else
            {
                bResult = E_IMAGEFILE_NOMEMORYTOLOAD;
            }
        }
        else
        {

            bResult = E_IMAGEFILE_MISSING;
        }
        cFile.Close();
        delete [] pBuff;
    }
    return bResult;
}
```

Image scaling code

```cpp
CPicture* CPicture::GetScaledClone(double fRatioX, double fRatioY)
    if(m_pXImage)
    {
        CPicture* pPic = new CPicture();
        pPic->m_nTotalParts = m_nTotalParts;
        pPic->m_pXImage = new CxImage(*m_pXImage);

        CSize size = GetSize();
        long lX = static_cast<LONG>(size.cx*fRatioX);
        long lY = static_cast<LONG>(size.cy*fRatioY);
        if(m_nTotalParts > 1)
        {
            int nX = lX % m_nTotalParts;
            int nY = nX * lY/lX;
            lX -= nX;
            lY -= nY;
        }

        pPic->m_pXImage->Resample(lX, lY, 0);
        return pPic;
    }
```

Comment: `CPicture` and `CxImage` are not standard MFC classes, we don't know much about them. The code for `CPicture` looks inefficient as it allocates another `CPicture` and `CxImage` object. You could try a different picture class which draws itself at different sizes on demand, and it caches the image for different sizes.

Comment: I use ImgSource libraries. Sadly they are no longer in business and I had to buy a copy of their source code so I could build the lib files for new releases of Visual Studio.

Comment: I've found [stb_image_resize](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image_resize.h) reasonably performant and it is able to do high quality resampling (it is easy to add even higher quality filters like "lanczos"). It also handles alpha channels well. As Barmak wrote, you should not reallocate resampled images all the time, but only keep source images. Resample on-the-fly when you actually need to draw something. [Buffered paint API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-bufferedpaintinit) can help with managing offscreen buffers.

Comment: HI Barmak Shemirani, could you please share little more detail on "any other picture class which draws itself ".Is there any library exist for better image rendering in diffrent sizes. Please suggest.